# How to create a high-resolution offscreen fragment shader?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I figured out my fragment shader is limited to the pixel dimensions of the OpenGL ES viewport.

Could I create an "offscreen fragment shader" or rendering environment which has a lot more pixels for rendering?

Comment: A fragment shader is resolution independent, what you need is an offscreen rendertarget, which is commonly known as framebuffer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fragment shaders take values created by the rasterization after the vertex shader. What you need to do is to create a Texture (very large texture), bind it to a FBO (you can look at OGL's doc for that, it's not very complicated) and render to it. Before the offscreen render, use the

`glViewPort`

function to define the rendering width and height. Before this offscreen rendering, use your fragment shader and all will work fine. Good luck :)

Comment: I created a sample application which does this kind of rendering to an offscreen FBO using an OpenGL ES 2.0 shader program as part of my post [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios), so the code I used there could be modified to handle a larger image as well.  It demonstrates what you describe above.

Comment: Thanks Tuxer & Brad! That's great!